# Why does the Torah repeat the prohibition against touching Har Sinai?

Tags: parashas-yisro, parshanut-torah-comment

First it says

> כָּל הַנֹּגֵעַ בָּהָר מוֹת יוּמָת

Then a Posuk later:

> אִם בְּהֵמָה אִם אִישׁ לֹא יִחְיֶה

Why is there a double death warning?

Comment: In jest, I would say that Hashem knew how Jews are, (every Jew needs to test the "wet paint",) so he needed a double warning to keep them off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Daas Zekeinim explains that someone who touched the mountain got killed through stoning. The second warning is that those that stone the one who touched the mountain should do it from afar.

Comment: I wish you would explain where you see that